# Disable kendogrid filter on particular column

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I need to disable the `Kendo` filter option on particular column on click of a `button`. I gave a shot as mentioned in link [Grid Custom Filter for Columns Not In Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008371/grid-custom-filter-for-columns-not-in-grid) but it throws error since filterable is not defined. Please help.

```
function ButtonClick() {
var TestGridDetails = $("#TestGrid").data("kendoGrid");
TestGridDetails.columns[6].filterable(false);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can't just change one column value; you can change options globally with the setOptions method but you need to define all of the columns' details.

```
function ButtonClick() {
  var TestGridDetails = $("#TestGrid").data("kendoGrid"),
      columnsConfig = TestGridDetails.options.columns;
  columnsConfig[6].filterable = false;
  TestGridDetails.setOptions({columns: columnsConfig});
}
```